# Conditionally derive Show for existential type parameterized on type constructor

Tags: haskell

Suppose I have a data type like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
data X a = forall b. Show b => X (a b)
```

I would like to derive `Show (X a)`, but of course I can only do so if there is an instance of `Show (a b)`.  I'm tempted to write

```
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
deriving instance Show (a b) => Show (X a)
```

but unfortunately the type variable `b` is not available in the instance context because it is bound by the forall.

My next attempt was to move the `Show (a b)` context into the forall in the data type definition, like so:

```
data X a = forall b. Show (a b) => X (a b)
deriving instance Show (X a)
```

This compiles, but unfortunately now I've lost the ability to construct an `X` with an unshowable `(a b)`.

Is there any way to allow `X` to be constructed with any `(a b)`, and then conditionally derive `Show (X a)` only if `(a b)` is showable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a deficiency in the Prelude classes. There's a nice way around it though embodied in the [`prelude-extras`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/prelude-extras) package. I'll outline it below.

We'd like to create a higher-kinded `Show` class. It looks like this

```
class Show1 a where
  show1 :: Show b => a b -> String
```

Then we can at least accurately express our desired constraint like

```
deriving instance Show1 a => Show (X a)
```

Unfortunately, the compiler does not yet have enough information to achieve this derivation. We need to show that `(Show b, Show1 a)` is enough to derive `Show (a b)`. To do so we'll need to enable some (scary, but sanely-used) extensions

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances         #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverlappingInstances      #-}

instance (Show b, Show1 a) => Show (a b) where
  show = show1
```

And now that we have that proof the compiler will be able to derive what we need

```
data X a = forall b . Show b => X (a b)
deriving instance Show1 a => Show (X a)
```

Comment: Too bad. Everything the GHC manual says about OverlappingInstances is scary.

Comment: Yeah, it's not terrifically recommended. Show1 can also clobber other instances pretty easily.

Answer (score 5):

I would take a similar but slightly different approach to J. Abrahamson's answer.

Precisely what you ask for can't be done, because type classes need to be resolved *statically*, but the existence of `Show (a b)` might be *dynamic* depending on the instantation of `b`. This instantiation is hidden inside the `X` value and therefore not visible to the type checker when you have nothing but an `X b` of unknown origin.

It would be nice to write a condition on `a` like `Show (a b)` exists whenever `Show b` does, because then the existence of `Show (a b)` isn't actually dependent on `b` as we already know that `Show b` is always true.

We can't write that condition directly, but we can express something like it using GADTs:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
data ShowDict a where
    ShowDict :: Show a => ShowDict a
```

The `ShowDict a` type provides a sort of reification of the `Show a` class - it's something we can pass around and define functions over.

In particular we can now define a `Show1` class that expresses the condition `Show (a b)` whenever we have a `Show b`:

```
class Show1 a where
    show1Dict :: ShowDict b -> ShowDict (a b)
```

And now we can define `Show (X a)` in terms of `Show1`, by constructing `ShowDict (a b)` and then pattern-matching on it to reveal the `Show` instance:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
instance Show1 a => Show (X a) where
    show (X (v :: a b)) =
       case show1Dict ShowDict :: ShowDict (a b) of
           ShowDict -> "X (" ++ show v ++ ")"
```

A more complete implementation would also include the other members of `Show` (`showsPrec` and `showList`).

The nice thing about this solution is that we can easily define `Show1` for `[]`, automatically reusing the underlying `Show` instance:

```
instance Show1 [] where
    show1Dict ShowDict = ShowDict
```

I also prefer to avoid the very generic `Show (a b)` instance from J. Abrahamson's answer, but the downside of having to put the logic in the `Show` instance for `X` is that we end up having to implement it manually rather than getting the auto-derived behaviour for the constructor.

Comment: I agree with this answer generally, but it's worth noting that these solutions lose the deriving. That's probably simply an unavoidable consequence, though. Deriving and existentials don't play nicely very often.

Comment: I'd actually forgotten about displaying the `X` constructor in the `Show` instance, which is a significant upside to your answer. But yes, it won't often be possible to use deriving on an existential.