# List of Functors

Tags: haskell

This might apply for any type class, but lets do it for Functors as I know them better. I wan't to construct this list.

```
l = [Just 1, [1,2,3], Nothing, Right 4]
```

and then

```
map (fmap (+1)) l
```

to get

```
[Just 2, [2,3,4], Nothing, Right 5]
```

I know they are all Functors that contain Ints so it might be possible. How can I do this?

**Edit**

This is turning out to be messier than it would seem. In Java or C# you'd declare the `IFunctor` interface and then just write

```
List<IFunctor> l = new List<IFunctor> () {
    new Just (1),
    new List<Int>() {1,2,3},
    new Nothing<Int>(),
    new Right (5)
}
```

assuming `Maybe`, `List` and `Either` implement the `IFunctor`. Naturally `Just` and `Nothing` extend `Maybe` and `Right` and `Left` extend `Either`. Not satisfied with this problem being easier to resolve on these languages!!!

There should cleaner way in Haskell :(

Comment: You could do this using existential types, but how would you get the values back out of the resulting list?

Comment: I thought of using pattern matching against the known possibilities.

Comment: If you want to pattern match, you might want to use functor coproducts. `data (f :+: g) a = FLeft (f a) | FRight (g a)`. Then `l :: [Maybe :+: []]`, and you have to tag the elements of `l` with `FLeft` or `FRight` depending on which functor they are. It's a bit messy, but the power is there.

Comment: @luqui can you give a more detailed explanation maybe in an answer? I don't know about coproducts.

Comment: @luqui: why not just an explicit discriminated union?

Comment: You can't actually just implement `IFunctor` on `Maybe` etc in C# because it doesn't have higher-kinded types: http://joeduffyblog.com/2008/11/04/longing-for-higherkinded-c/

Comment: This kind of question is often asked by Haskell newbies who are trying to translate OO idioms into Haskell and then wondering why it doesn't work. What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: As a previous comment asks, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam here is my implementation. I don't seem to have a problem with Maybe implementing IFunctor. Works great in production.

Comment: @PaulJohnson its a little rude for you to assume that thats my intention. Actually the C# part was added later as a final thought. The whole question is actually out of pure curiosity, I am not trying to accomplish anything. I am still puzzled by the fact that having such a strong type system, you can't easily group elements of a certain type class. Maybe you don't need this in practice, its just something that occurred to me.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam ohhhh I see what you mean, I crashed into that wall of higher-kindedness. But you realize that posing things like this is a little silly because you are in OOP, so actually the `T` in `T<B> FMap<A, B>(Func<A, B> f, T<A> a)` of `IFunctor` is the known by the **actual object**, and that `FMap` is actually going to be a `method`, so you can reduce this to `IFunctor<B> FMap<B> (Func<A,B> f)`.

Comment: Then the *actual* `FMap`static function (not the method) is just `public static IFunctor<B> FMap<A,B> (Func<A,B> f, IFunctor<A> F) {return F.FMap (f); }`

Comment: @CristianGarcia: that route is a reasonable approximation, but it means that `fmap (+1) (Just 1)` isn't statically guaranteed to be `Maybe Int` - a misbehaving implementation might `return [1]` instead. You can do a bit better with the "curiously recurring template pattern" but you still end up needing downcasts.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam, well I have two ways to doing it: `FMap (add1, Maybe.Just(1))` where `Maybe.Just` is a helper function that creates a `new Just` of the proper type. The direct way is `FMap (add1, new Just<int> (1))`. The thing is that you get back an `IFunctor<int>`, but you **do** know it contains a `Just<int>`.

Comment: I'm afraid this does very much fit in the "I'm having more trouble than I expected driving my new aeroplane around the carpark" category of problems.  in reality, a list isn't the best way of storing non-homogenous data, in very much the same way that an iterator isn't the easiest way to produce it. It's not impossible, it's just inconvenient because it's the wrong tool. Why not use a record for the disparate bits and lists only for when you have multiples of exactly the same thing?

Comment: @AndrewC This is more a proof of concept, I am not coding anything to do with this.

Answer (score 14):

In Haskell, downcasting is not allowed. You can use `AnyFunctor`, but the trouble with that is there is no longer any way to get back to a functor that you know.  When you have an `AnyFunctor a`, all you know is that you have an `f a` for some `f`, so all you can do is `fmap` (getting you another `AnyFunctor`).  Thus, `AnyFunctor a` is in fact equivalent to `()`.

You can add structure to `AnyFunctor` to make it more useful, and we'll see a bit of that later on.

### Functor Coproducts

But first, I'll share the way that I would probably end up doing this in a real program: by using functor combinators.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

infixl 1 :+:   -- declare this to be a left-associative operator

data (f :+: g) a = FLeft (f a) | FRight (g a)
instance (Functor f, Functor g) => Functor (f :+: g) where
    -- left as an exercise
```

As the data type reads, `f :+: g` is a functor whose values can be either `f a` or `g a`.

Then you can use, for example:

```
l :: [ (Maybe :+: []) Int ]
l = [ FLeft (Just 1), FRight [2,3,4], FLeft Nothing ]
```

And you can observe by pattern matching:

```
getMaybe :: (Maybe :+: g) a -> Maybe a
getMaybe (FLeft v) = v
getMaybe (FRight _) = Nothing
```

It gets ugly as you add more functors:

```
l :: [ (Maybe :+: [] :+: Either Int) Int ]
l = [ FLeft (FLeft Nothing), FRight (Right 42) ]
-- Remember that we declared :+: left-associative.
```

But I recommend it as long as you can handle the ugliness, because it tracks the list of possible functors in the type, which is an advantage. (Perhaps you eventually need more structure beyond what `Functor` can provide; as long as you can provide it for `(:+:)`, you're in good territory.)

You can make the terms a bit cleaner by creating an explicit union, as Ganesh recommends:

```
data MyFunctors a
    = FMaybe (Maybe a)
    | FList [a]
    | FEitherInt (Either Int a)
    | ...
```

But you pay by having to re-implement `Functor` for it (`{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}` can help). I prefer to put up with the ugliness, and work at a high enough level of abstraction where it doesn't get too ugly (i.e. once you start writing `FLeft (FLeft ...)` it's time to refactor & generalize).

Coproduct can be found in the [comonad-transformers](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/comonad-transformers-2.0.3) package if you don't want to implement it yourself (it's good exercise though). Other common functor combinators are in the `Data.Functor.` namespace in the [transformers](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.2.2.0) package.

### Existentials with Downcasting

`AnyFunctor` can also be extended to allow downcasting.  Downcasting must be explicitly enabled by adding the [`Typeable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Data-Typeable.html) class to whatever you intend to downcast. Every concrete type is an instance of `Typeable`; type constructors are instances of `Typeable1` (1 argument); etc.  But it doesn't come for free on type variables, so you need to add class constraints. So the `AnyFunctor` solution becomes:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

import Data.Typeable

data AnyFunctor a where
    AnyFunctor :: (Functor f, Typeable1 f) => f a -> AnyFunctor a

instance Functor AnyFunctor where
    fmap f (AnyFunctor v) = AnyFunctor (fmap f v)
```

Which allows downcasting:

```
downcast :: (Typeable1 f, Typeable a) => AnyFunctor a -> Maybe (f a)
downcast (AnyFunctor f) = cast f
```

This solution is actually cleaner than I had expected to be, and may be worth pursuing.

Comment: You can leave out `Typeable a` in the constraints. The `a` variable is exposed (unlike `f`) so the constraint can be added just where it's needed. That should then solve the `fmap` problem. `downcast` then needs a `Typeable a` constraint which is no problem to add.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam, great observation.  This is actually quite nice now.

Comment: With the new polykinded `Typeable` you no longer need `Typeable1`.

Comment: [Functor coproducts don't have to be ugly/a lot of typing](http://www.cs.ru.nl/~W.Swierstra/Publications/DataTypesALaCarte.pdf)

Comment: With Functors and coproducts you can just view this as an "HList1". It's just the usual trick of having a type level representation of the value level list. It can be made a lot prettier with GADTs + DataKinds to promote a proper list to type level

Answer (score 7):

One approach is to use [*existentials*](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Existential_type):

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
data AnyFunctor v where
    AnyFunctor :: Functor f => f v -> AnyFunctor v

instance Functor AnyFunctor where
    fmap f (AnyFunctor fv) = AnyFunctor (fmap f fv)
```

The input list you ask for in your question isn't possible as it stands because it's not correctly typed, so some wrapping like `AnyFunctor` is likely to be necessary however you approach it.

You can make the input list by wrapping each value in the `AnyFunctor` data constructor:

```
[AnyFunctor (Just 1), AnyFunctor [1,2,3],
 AnyFunctor Nothing, AnyFunctor (Right 4)]
```

Note that when you use `fmap (+1)` it's a good idea to use an explicit type signature for the `1` to avoid any problems with numeric overloading, e.g. `fmap (+(1::Integer))`.

The difficulty with `AnyFunctor v` as it stands is that you can't actually do much with it - you can't even look at the results because it isn't an instance of `Show`, let alone extract a value for future use.

It's a little tricky to make it into an instance of `Show`. If we add a `Show (f v)` constraint to the `AnyFunctor` data constructor, then the `Functor` instance stops working because there's no guarantee it'll produce an instance of `Show` itself. Instead we need to use a sort of "higher-order" typeclass `Show1`, as discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24482561/conditionally-derive-show-for-existential-type-parameterized-on-type-constructor/24483516#24483516):

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data AnyFunctor v where
    AnyFunctor :: (Show1 f, Functor f) => f v -> AnyFunctor v

instance Functor AnyFunctor where
    fmap f (AnyFunctor fv) = AnyFunctor (fmap f fv)

data ShowDict a where
    ShowDict :: Show a => ShowDict a

class Show1 a where
    show1Dict :: ShowDict b -> ShowDict (a b)

instance Show v => Show (AnyFunctor v) where
    show (AnyFunctor (v :: f v)) =
        case show1Dict ShowDict :: ShowDict (f v) of
           ShowDict -> "AnyFunctor (" ++ show v ++ ")"

instance Show1 [] where
    show1Dict ShowDict = ShowDict

instance Show1 Maybe where
    show1Dict ShowDict = ShowDict

instance Show a => Show1 (Either a) where
    show1Dict ShowDict = ShowDict
```

In ghci this gives the following (I've broken the lines for readability):

```
*Main> map (fmap (+1)) [AnyFunctor (Just 1), AnyFunctor [1,2,3],
                          AnyFunctor Nothing, AnyFunctor (Right 4)]

[AnyFunctor (Just 2),AnyFunctor ([2,3,4]),
 AnyFunctor (Nothing),AnyFunctor (Right 5)]
```

The basic idea is to express the idea that a type constructor like `Nothing`, `[]` or `Either a` "preserves" the `Show` constraint, using the `Show1` class to say that `Show (f v)` is available whenever `Show v` is available.

The same trick applies with other typeclasses. For example @luqui's answer shows how you can extract values using the `Typeable` class, which already has a built-in `Typeable1` variant. Each type class that you add limits the things that you can put into `AnyFunctor`, but also means you can do more things with it.

Comment: Error ```Constructor AnyFunctor' should have no arguments, but has been given 1
    In the pattern: AnyFunctor fv
    In an equation for fmap:
        fmap f (AnyFunctor fv) = AnyFunctor (fmap f fv)
    In the instance declaration for Functor AnyFunctor```

Comment: Sorry, copy and pasted the wrong thing - check now.

Comment: "Could not deduce (v ~ f v)
from the context (a ~ f v, Functor f)
...
AnyFunctor :: forall (f :: * -> *) v.
Functor f =>
f v -> AnyFunctor (f v),
in an equation for `fmap'
...
`v' is a rigid type variable bound by
a pattern with constructor
AnyFunctor :: forall (f :: * -> *) v.
Functor f =>
f v -> AnyFunctor (f v),
in an equation for `fmap'
...
Expected type: f a
Actual type: f v
In the second argument of `fmap', namely `fv'
In the first argument of `AnyFunctor', namely `(fmap f fv)'
In the expression: AnyFunctor (fmap f fv)"

Comment: Thanks! But how do I set up my list?

Comment: @CristianGarcia, `l = [AnyFunctor (Just 1), AnyFunctor [1,2,3], ...]`

Comment: @CristianGarcia - I've updated my answer with an example and also how to "Show" the results.

Answer (score 4):

One option would be to create a specific data type for your use case, with the additional advantage of having proper names for things.

Another would be to create a specialized `* -> *` tuples as:

```
newtype FTuple4 fa fb fc fd r = FTuple4 (fa r, fb r, fc r, fd r)
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
```

So the tuple is homogeneous in values, but heterogeneous in functors.
Then you can define

```
instance (Functor fa, Functor fb, Functor fc, Functor fd) =>
         Functor (FTuple4 fa fb fc fd) where
    fmap f (FTuple4 (a, b, c, d)) =
        FTuple4 (fmap f a, fmap f b, fmap f c, fmap f d)
```

and

```
main = let ft = FTuple4 (Just 1,
                         [1,2,3],
                         Nothing,
                         Right 4 :: Either String Int)
       in print $ fmap (+ 1) ft
```

With this approach, you can pattern match on the result easily, without losing information about the types of the individual elements, their order etc. And, you can have similar instances for `Foldable`, `Traversable`, `Applicative` etc.

Also you don't need to implement the `Functor` instance yourself, you can use [GHC's  deriving extensions](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/users_guide/deriving.html#deriving-typeable), so all you need to write to get all the instances is is just

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor, DeriveFoldable, DeriveTraversable #-}

import Data.Foldable
import Data.Traversable

newtype FTuple4 fa fb fc fd r = FTuple4 (fa r, fb r, fc r, fd r)
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Functor, Foldable, Traversable)
```

And even this can be further automated for arbitrary length using [Template Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Template_Haskell).

The advantage of this approach is mainly in the fact that it just wraps ordinary tuples, so you can seamlessly switch between `(,,,)` and `FTuple4`, if you need.

---

Another alternative, without having your own data type, would be to use nested [functor products](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.1.0/docs/Data-Functor-Product.html), since what you're describing is just a product of 4 functors.

```
import Data.Functor.Product

main = let ft = Pair (Just 1)
                  (Pair [1,2,3]
                    (Pair Nothing
                         (Right 4 :: Either String Int)
                  ))
           (Pair a (Pair b (Pair c d))) = fmap (+ 1) ft
        in print (a, b, c, d)
```

This is somewhat verbose, but you can do much better by creating your own functor product using type operators:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators, DeriveFunctor #-}

data (f :*: g) a = f a :*: g a
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Functor)
infixl 1 :*:

main = let a :*: b :*: c :*: d = fmap (+ 1) $ Just 1 :*:
                                              [1,2,3] :*:
                                              Nothing :*:
                                              (Right 4 :: Either String Int)
        in print (a, b, c, d)
```

This gets probably as terse and universal as possible.

Comment: You could also use a pattern synonym to simplify it: `pattern a :*: b = Pair a b`.